How can I create a reply "chat thread" using JDA
Discord has a feature that can create a start thread to keep messages organized. I couldn't find how to do this with JDA.
I am not referring to programming threads.

You can use Message#createThreadChannel(name):
message.createThreadChannel("my topic").queue(channel -> {
  channel.sendMessage("my reply").queue();
});

